# Smooth arcs in quartz?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, quartz-graphics

While developing a rounded rectangle widget I encountered the following problem: path built with arcs looks ugly when stroked.

[picture http://img51.yfrog.com/img51/8919/quartzarc.png](http://img51.yfrog.com/img51/8919/quartzarc.png)

How to make the stroked arcs look nicer?

Answer (score 1):

One trick with quartz drawing is to offset things by half a pixel.  Try insetting your rect before drawing:

```
rect = CGRectInset( rect , -0.5 , -0.5 );
```

Doing +0.5 instead of -0.5 would make the rectangle smaller.

Comment: I found this at the very same moment. In my case it is positive offset that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Here's outline of the solution valid for any given line width:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat lineWidth=1.5;
    rect = CGRectInset(rect, lineWidth , lineWidth);
    ...
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
        ...
}
```